# xmlstarlet - concat multi-line value

Tags: linux, xml

Having xmlstarlet 1.3.1.

Given file.xml:

```
<entry>
  <message>Line 1
  Line 2 and so on
  </message>
</entry>
```

How can I select *message* and displaying its value in one line, while new lines replaced with "@" as following:

```
Line 1@Line 2 and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/entry/message" file.xml | tr -s "\n" "@"`

Note that there is an additional newline after *and so on* in your example.

Comment: I want the value be in one line. I've updated the question to clarify this point.